# ArcGis layers on mapbox gl

Tags: leaflet, arcgis, esri, mapbox-gl

I'm trying to add a layer from an api on ArcGis:
https://maps2.dcgis.dc.gov/dcgis/rest/services/DCGIS_DATA/Facility_and_Structure/MapServer/1

In leaflet it is posible with:

```
  L.esri.featureLayer({
  url:"https://maps2.dcgis.dc.gov/dcgis/rest/services/DCGIS_DATA/Facility_and_Structure/MapServer/1",
    style: function () {
    return { color: "#70ca49", weight: 2 };
    }
    }).addTo(map);
```

Is there a way to do this on mapboxgl?

Answer (score 1):

Hi [Jorge Monroy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8902917/jorge-monroy) - Mapbox GL JS expects the data sources as [such](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/#sources).  In your case where you're wanting to load building footprints from an ArcGIS REST Service, your best bet is to load them as a geojson.

It looks like you're publishing the services from ArcServer [10.31](https://maps2.dcgis.dc.gov/dcgis/rest/services).  In that case, the way that I've loaded ArcGIS REST services is by exposing them through [AGOL](https://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2014/12/16/arcgis-online-geojson/) as explained there.  If you have that option, that seems easiest.  Otherwise, there are other (work-arounds)[https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/13029/converting-arcgis-server-json-to-geojson] that I've no experience with.

Using Washington D.C. as an example, if you navigate to: http://opendata.dc.gov/datasets/building-footprints and then click on APIs, you can copy the link to the geojson service.

You can then load into MapboxGL JS through the [data](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/#geojsonsource) property of the geojson source shown there.

Answer (score 0):

You can use leaflet-mapbox-gl.js to integrate leaflet and mapbox. Get token from mapbox and add it to below example to make it work.

References: https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-leaflet

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet/dist/leaflet.css"/>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
    <link href='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v1.5.0/mapbox-gl.css' rel='stylesheet' />
    <script src='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v1.5.0/mapbox-gl.js'></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/mapbox-gl-leaflet/leaflet-mapbox-gl.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/esri-leaflet/dist/esri-leaflet.js"></script>
    <style>
      html, body, #map {
        margin:0; padding:0;  width : 100%; height : 100%;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script>
      var token = "";//add token before running this example

      const INITIAL_VIEW_STATE = {
          latitude: 45.528,
          longitude: -122.680,
          zoom: 13
        };

      var map = L.map('map').setView([45.528, -122.680], 13);
      L.esri.basemapLayer("NationalGeographic").addTo(map);
      var parks = L.esri.featureLayer({
        url: "https://services.arcgis.com/rOo16HdIMeOBI4Mb/arcgis/rest/services/Portland_Parks/FeatureServer/0",
        style: function () {
          return { color: "#70ca49", weight: 2 };
        }
      }).addTo(map);

      var gl = L.mapboxGL({
            accessToken: token,
            style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/dark-v10'
        }).addTo(map);

      //To add anything on mapbox, first access the mapbox using getMapboxMap()
      gl.getMapboxMap().on('load', () => {
          //To load any layer on mapbox
          //gl.getMapboxMap().addLayer();
      });
      var popupTemplate = "<h3>{NAME}</h3>{ACRES} Acres<br><small>Property ID: {PROPERTYID}<small>";

      parks.bindPopup(function(e){
        return L.Util.template(popupTemplate, e.feature.properties)
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```